# Commands \mapsto and \longmapsto from Right to Left

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Concerning [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220145/how-to-inverse-this-function-inverse-exponential-function-with-arctan/220199#220199): How do I make \mapsto and \longmapsto point from right to left?

Comment: The suggestions given in [Left version of \mapsto](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26508/left-version-of-mapsto) at TeX.SE don't work in mathjax :-(

Comment: Here's a solution which works for me:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\longleftmapsto}{\text{\reflectbox{\$\longmapsto\$}}}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\newcommand{\testleft}{\leftarrow\!\shortmid}\newcommand{\testleftlong}{\longleftarrow\!\shortmid}$
I was only able to come up with this:
`\newcommand{\testleft}{\leftarrow\!\shortmid}`
`\newcommand{\testleftlong}{\longleftarrow\!\shortmid}`
which gives this: $\testleft$ and $\testleftlong$

The suggestions from [Left version of \mapsto at TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26508/left-version-of-mapsto) don't work in mathjax: 
$\leftmapsto$, $\mapsfrom$.

Comment: For now, I'm going with this one.

Comment: robjohn suggested this `\longleftarrow{\raise{.4pt}{\hspace{-5pt}\shortmid}}` in his [comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6428/arrows#comment22850_6429).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `\mapsfrom` does not seem to be supported in MathJax, but that is what you are looking for, I believe.  However, there is a `\leftarrowtail`: $\leftarrowtail$

There is a [closed thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26508/left-version-of-mapsto) on the $\TeX$ board. The thread that this was closed as a duplicate of points to a useful tool: [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), which does not find the `\mapsfrom` symbol (for me at least).

---

#### Update

I have found two alternatives; one that uses `\unicode{x21a4}` which gives $\unicode{x21a4}$, and another that uses `\style{display:inline-block; transform:scale(-1,1);}{\mapsto}` which gives $\style{display:inline-block; transform:scale(-1,1);}{\mapsto}$.

So adding
`\newcommand{\mapsfrom}{\mathrel{\unicode{x21a4}}}`
or
`\newcommand{\mapsfrom}{\mathrel{\style{display:inline-block; transform:scale(-1,1);}{\mapsto}}}`
should provide the missing `\mapsfrom` command.

Comment: Detexify gives me mapsfrom.

Comment: @Phira: After many tries, I did get `\mapsfrom`. However, `\mapsfrom` is not supported in MathJax. Something like $\longleftarrow{\raise{.4pt}{\hspace{-5pt}\shortmid}}$ could be used instead.