# Is there a chart corresponding every [Math.SE] LaTeX code to its Unicode character counterpart?

Tags: support, mathjax, unicode

For example, between dollar-signs “\in” displays "$\in$" which is the inline representation of the ‘element-of’ symbol '∈' (which displays equivalently entered instead of its LaTex ASCII code between \$\.\$) identified by U+2208; thus, 'in'↤↦‘2208’.

Currently, when I want to enter a Unicode character directly (instead of relying on it being rendered via LaTeX) I just google the best/official descriptor of it that I know (such as "reverse maps-to arrow" for ↤, as ["\mapsfrom"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/946772) apparently be not here existent) and usually find it copy-able from a Wikipedia page, unless I know its \$\.\$ name then I manage to copy it sometimes from indexed math.stackexchange Q or A via search-engine.

Surely all their assignations are available publicly  somewhere (with the actual correct correspondences)?

Comment: Just curious, why do you ever want to use unicode instead of the Jax command?

Comment: You might like this earlier post at TeX.SE: [An extensive list of LaTeX symbols and Unicode equivalents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162385/an-extensive-list-of-latex-symbols-and-unicode-equivalents)

Comment: @hardmath ~~aye that is helpful. However, if existent it would be nice to see the *exact* character- correspondence (since some look quite similar, but one is the official 'math' one for particular context ..rather than just getting by "as needed").

Comment: @Don Thousand ~~1.In titles it saves characters.  2. It feels more pure; less extraneous markup the better. (I am aware of the purposes for using LaTeX/MathJax, and am not suggesting to abandon it.) 3. It is easier to copy an "actual" line of math text.

Comment: hardmath~~ At the TeX.SE page you linked (thankYou, btw), @Marcello Herreshoff (direct Answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438475)) linked to [a page](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/data/unimathsymbols.txt) that appears to list the "actual Unicode slots" as I requested , but without providing the actual characters (though a Unicode lookup table would complement it nicely).

Comment: @egreg ~~At your [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168129) you point readers to using either XeLaTex or LuaLaTex for accessing conversion to/from Unicode mathematical characters, which you note in comment to it that you  compiled the list using the former.  I am not yet familiarized with the process. Does it take much data?

Comment: @11qq00 You shouldn't be hitting anywhere near the cap imo for a good title. Unicode math in titles looks poor compared to Jax, and can be browser dependent, which is not great if you want the most number of people to see your question.

Comment: @Don Thousand ~~Using \$-parameters it looks identical using the \*actual* character (e.g. '∋'). Without being paramterized it might not render properly on all browsers/OSs, but that is moot (unless I am mistaken, i.e. that some browsers even at that might take issue). $\quad$As for indexing it, you can then use the spelled-out \$- or \$\$- parameterized versions (e.g. "\ni") inside the actual body of the Q or A.$\quad$ As for title not needing that many characters: For the most part true, but options are still nice; as is$\:$ knowledge.

Comment: On [math.se] I definitely prefer writing MathJax. But when I needed, for some reason, the Unicode character, the list on Wikipedia was enough for me: [List of mathematical symbols by subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject).

Comment: This website allows you to enter LaTeX code, and get the Unicode translation.

 https://www.unicodeit.net/

Comment: When I have ever wanted this, my solution has been to type it in mathjax in an answer box  and then copying the rendered mathjax from the preview. eg. `$\ni \oplus$`$\ni \oplus$ gives me ∋⊕